# Golbal GTNI database (Or at least for luxury products)

Tags: barcode, product, google-shopping, google-product-search

does anyone know of a public or purchaseable database which contains GTNI codes for luxury goods? (watches in particular).

Google shopping will make this a requirement now (See here the [details](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6352134?hl=en)) and I can't find any source which contains this information.

Here you can see closer detials regarding these [unique ID's.](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find the GTIN for a specific product from any source other than:

1. The item itself
2. From the manufacturer

Other ways to determine the GTIN for an item are not accurate. Manufacturers buy batches to GTINs from GS1 and can arbitrarily apply them to products at their will.

You can, however validate a GTIN here:

https://www.gs1us.org/tools/gs1-company-database-gepir

By clicking on "GTIN" in the tab strip.

Note that this will not help you find a GTIN for an item, it will just tell you who a GTIN was registered to and whether it is valid or not.

Matt.